# Php Laravel confirm password in vuejs

Tags: php, vue.js

I have this simple compare of password and confirm password. Is there any better way or approach to enhance it?. Any recommendation is appreciated.

I have search vee-validate but sadly I don't know how to use it in my project even how many times I search different sites that has a example on how to use it.

**HTML Code**

```
   <form @submit.prevent="SaveUser">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Name</label>
              <input
                v-model="form.name"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                autocomplete="off"
                class="form-control"
                :class="{
                  'is-invalid': form.errors.has('name'),
                }"
              />
              <has-error :form="form" field="name"></has-error>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Username</label>
              <input
                v-model="form.username"
                type="text"
                name="username"
                autocomplete="off"
                class="form-control"
                :class="{
                  'is-invalid': form.errors.has('username'),
                }"
              />
              <has-error :form="form" field="username"></has-error>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Select Role</label>
              <select
                v-model="form.role"
                name="role"
                class="form-control"
                :class="{
                  'is-invalid': form.errors.has('role'),
                }"
              >
                <option value="" disabled>--Select Role--</option>
                <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                <option value="cashier">Cashier</option>
              </select>
              <has-error :form="form" field="role"></has-error>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input
                v-model="form.password"
                type="password"
                name="password"
                autocomplete="off"
                class="form-control"
                :class="{
                  'is-invalid': form.errors.has('password'),
                }"
              />
              <has-error :form="form" field="password"></has-error>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Confirm Password</label>
              <input
                v-model="form.confirm_password"
                type="password"
                name="confirm_password"
                autocomplete="off"
                class="form-control"
                :class="{
                  'is-invalid': form.errors.has('confirm_password'),
                }"
              />
              <has-error :form="form" field="confirm_password"></has-error>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save User</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

**Save User Code**

```
   SaveUser() {
  console.log(this.form);
  this.$Progress.start();
  if (this.form.confirm_password != "" && this.form.password != "") {
    if (this.form.confirm_password == this.form.password) {
      Toast.fire({
        type: "success",
        title: "User Successfully Save",
      });
    } else {
      Toast.fire({
        type: "warning",
        title: "Failed",
      });
    }
  }
},
```